# Change color of a custom UIButton on .selected state

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have designed a radial gradient button for my app's home screen:

```
    class RadialGradientButton: UIButton {

    var insideColor: UIColor = ColorScheme.limeGreen
    var outsideColor: UIColor = UIColor.white

    var gradientLocation: CGFloat = 0.9

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let colors = [insideColor.cgColor, outsideColor.cgColor] as CFArray
        let center = CGPoint(x: rect.size.width / 2, y: rect.size.height / 2)

        let endRadius = rect.size.width / 2

        let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: nil, colors: colors, locations: [gradientLocation, 1.0])

        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.drawRadialGradient(gradient!, startCenter: center, startRadius: 0.0, endCenter: center, endRadius: endRadius, options: .drawsBeforeStartLocation)
    }

    }
```

Now with this button I've ran into a user experience issue: when the button is tapped, its appearance is not changed in any way because of gradient color settings. I want it to behave like any system button - that is, `insideColor` should get darker on `.selected` state.

I've tried to play around with `setNeedsDisplay()` when `Touch Down` and `Touch Up Inside` events are triggered, but this method does not perform immediate redrawing, plus can be harsh on performance.

Maybe someone here can lead me in a right direction.

Comment: did you ever get a solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

`draw()` method is called when a view is first displayed or when an event occurs that invalidates a visible part of the view. Overriding this method, UIKit creates and configures a graphics context for drawing and render your gradient layer on it. That's why your selected background is not working.

You can achieve this behaviour by insert two layer on your view- one for highlighted and another for normal state. Later change behaviour on touch event.

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore


class RoundedButton: UIButton {

var gradientBackgroundLayer : CAGradientLayer?
var selectedLayer : CALayer?

var insideColor: UIColor = UIColor.green;
var outsideColor: UIColor = UIColor.white;
var gradientLocation: NSNumber = 0.9;
let kAnimationLength:CGFloat = 0.15;

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame);
    commonInit();
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder);
    commonInit();
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib();
    commonInit();
}

func commonInit() {
    self.backgroundColor = nil;
    self.clipsToBounds = true;
    self.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState.normal)

    let colors : [CGColor] = [insideColor.cgColor, outsideColor.cgColor];
    let locations : [NSNumber] = [0,gradientLocation];

    let layer : CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer();
    layer.frame = self.bounds;
    layer.colors = colors;
    layer.locations = locations;

    self.gradientBackgroundLayer = layer;

    let selectedLayer : CALayer = CALayer();
    selectedLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    selectedLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    self.selectedLayer = selectedLayer;
}

func performLayout() {
    self.gradientBackgroundLayer?.frame = self.bounds;
    self.selectedLayer?.frame = self.bounds;

    self.layer.insertSublayer(self.gradientBackgroundLayer!, at: 1);
    self.layer.insertSublayer(self.selectedLayer!, at: 0);

    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height / 2.0;
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews();
    performLayout();
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event);

    UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(kAnimationLength), delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.isHighlighted = true;
        self.selectedLayer?.isHidden = false;
        self.gradientBackgroundLayer?.isHidden = true;
    }, completion: nil);
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event);

    UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(kAnimationLength), delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.isHighlighted = false;
        self.gradientBackgroundLayer?.isHidden = false;
        self.selectedLayer?.isHidden = true;
    }, completion: nil);
}
```

}

Try this. Hope it will work.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Similar situation where instead of having a gradient inside a layer I have a drop shadow. Works just fine too. Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

when touch Up Inside.

```
if self.mButton.isSelected = true {
       self.mButton.isSelected = false
       self.mButton.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.red, forState: .normal)
}
else{
       self.mButton.isSelected = true
       self.mButton.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.blue, forState: .normal)
}
```

and you can use this code in viewDidLoad()

Comment: Problem is I’m dealing with a custom gradient color rather than system background color. And I cannot find an efficient way to redraw it when button reacts to touch.